# Getting Jenkins Warning - "A secret was passed to sh using Groovy String interpolation"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, string-interpolation

After running jenkins job, in console I am facing warning message as,

```
"Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure"
```

My code looks like,

```
steps. withCredentials([
    steps.string(
         credentialsld: 'git-oauth-token-read',
         variable: 'GitOauthToken'
     )
})
{
    steps.sh(returnStdout: false,
          script:
               "git remote add mainline https://xxx:${new Jobs().getToken()}@github.com/;"
     )
 }
```

Here,

```
new Jobs().getToken() - returns the env.GitOauthToken
```

I tried using different combinations of single and double quotes to the script, but I am not able to remove this warning.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need the `new Jobs().getToken() `? you can just use the token as an environment variable in the `sh` command: `script: 'git remote add mainline https://xxx:$GitOauthToken@github.com/'`

Comment: @NoamHelmer, thank you for your reply. Actually this one is a old code. I tried replacing {new Jobs().getToken()} with 'GitOauthToken' but still getting this warning.@NoamHelmer do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you change the double quotes (`""`) to single ones (`''`) like in my example?

Comment: Yes, tried with this.

Comment: And you still get the same warning? - that is wired as using single quotes means there is no longer any string interpolation.

Comment: I had used this with double quotes and returned error as "No such property: GitOauthToken for class"